# <li> in the bottom of sidebar

Tags: html, css

[Image of the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P13BO.png)

Hello, how I can put the "Déconnexion" element at the bottom of the sidebar, whatever the screen size of the user.

My code looks like that :

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="profil">
    <div class="photo-profil">
      <img src="img/users_pdp/zenitsu.jpg" alt="photo-profil">
    </div>
    <div class="nom">
      <span>User</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#">Ma liste</a></li>
    <li class="genres-li"><a>Genres <span class="arrow_carrot-down"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="./categories.php?categorie=film">Films</a></li>
    <li><a href="./categories.php?categorie=serie">Séries</a></li>
    <li><a href="./categories.php?categorie=anime">Animes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mon compte</a></li>
    <li class="sign-out"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> Déconnexion</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean? The `Déconnexion` is already at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry, I bad explained. I wanted to "Déconnexion" go to the bottom of screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking from your image, it looks like you have absolute position for your sidebar.

Since you need the nav-list to take up entirety of the available space, you can make use of flex.

1. Make your sidebar as a `display:flex`, with `flex-direction: column` to retain the layout.
2. add `flex: 1` to your `nav-links` to make it use of available space.
3. Change display property of `nav-links` to flex and direction as `column`
4. Add `margin-top: auto` to your sign-out to move it to the bottom.

Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/blendedideas/pen/ZEXzrOV) example.

Comment: That's work, thank you so much